# Send pinpoint push notification

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I want to send a push notification using c#.
This is what I've tried.

```
 var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("key", "secretkey");
 var a = new AmazonPinpointClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
 var mensaje = new SendMessagesRequest();
 mensaje.ApplicationId = "pinpoint proyect id";
 var request = new MessageRequest();
 ChannelType canal = Amazon.Pinpoint.ChannelType.GCM;
 var configuracionAdress = new AddressConfiguration();
 configuracionAdress.ChannelType = canal;
 string id = "device token";
  var dict = new Dictionary<string, AddressConfiguration>();
  dict.Add(id, configuracionAdress);
  request.Addresses = dict;
   var context = new Dictionary<string,string>();
  context.Add("Titulo", "Reunion");
  context.Add("Cuerpo", "Asistir");
  request.Context = context;

  mensaje.MessageRequest = request;
  a.SendMessages(mensaje);
```

debugging the code, the `SendMessages` method returns this.

[image: error]

any idea what I am doing wrong? thx

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified any message to sent. It will be a MessageConfiguration property in the **mensaje** object in your example above.